# Do Flutter applications support Microsoft Intune App SDK?

Tags: ios, flutter, intune

I'm considering investing in a course to learn Flutter (Google's UI toolkit for crafting beautiful, natively compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase).

Is it possible to integrate Flutter with the Microsoft Intune App SDK?

Does anyone have a sample code/functional application of this integration?